# react-vis doesn't draw second time ( react-vis draws only once or react-vis draws only for the first time )

Tags: reactjs, charts, jsx, react-vis

I have a component with react-vis in it. This component is in react-tabs, on the chart tab. When I access that tab for the first time it is drawn ok. Every time after that it is not drawn at all. What is the issue?

```
return (
                <div style={{
                    width: "95%",
                    height: "60vh",
                    marginLeft: "25px"
                }}>
                    <FlexibleXYPlot>
                        <HorizontalGridLines/>
                        <LineSeries
                            data={preparedData}/>
                        <XAxis title="1" position="middle"/>
                        <YAxis title="2" position="middle"/>
                    </FlexibleXYPlot>
                </div>

)
```

Answer (score 0):

well, I found in issues that it is a known bug.
https://github.com/uber/react-vis/issues/655

`<FlexibleXYPlot width={100} height={100}>` fixes that